# Flutter If Statement within Widget when rendering Text()

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I was wondering how to use if statements within widgets in Flutter.

The code below prompts the user to choose a date range using the DateRange package. I am trying to receive the date input, and print it using Text(...).

However, the if statement that I am using:

```
        Text((() {
          if(condition){
            return habitDates[0].toString() + "to " + habitDates[1].toString();}
          return "Pick Date";
        })()),
```

does not seem to update (it's constantly "Pick Date"), and I assume it is an issue regarding the widget's state.

Below is the full code:

```
class DateRange extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DateRangeState createState() => _DateRangeState();
}

class _DateRangeState extends State<DateRange> {

  List<DateTime> habitDates = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MaterialButton(
        color: Colors.grey[700],
        onPressed: () async {
          final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
              initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()),
              firstDate: new DateTime(2020),
              lastDate: new DateTime(2030),
          );
          if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
            picked.forEach((date) {
              habitDates.add(date);
              print(habitDates);
              }
            );
          }
        },
        child: Text("Pick date range", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
        ),
        Text((() {
          if(habitDates != null && habitDates.length == 2){
            return habitDates[0].toString() + "to " + habitDates[1].toString();}
          return "Pick Date";
        })()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Text(condition? 'first text' : 'second text')`

Comment: The condition is not updated if I do it as you recommended (it remains as false). I believe that I need to update the state of the Widget. Do you think creating 2 separate classes, and updating the state to notify the other works?

Comment: if you use `habitDates` in `build` then every time you change `habitDates` you have to call `setState()` method - https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#creating-a-stateful-widget

Answer (score 0):

You can call setState(() {...}); for update your Text Widget. Like this.

```
if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
  setState(() {
    picked.forEach((date) {
      habitDates.add(date);
      print(habitDates);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.